# Azure Dashboard - Metric: ADF pipeline limit

Tags: azure-data-factory

In Azure, we have dashboard which has Metrics for failed and success Data factory V2 pipelines in bar graph form. Graph gives result when number of pipeline selected in the filter is less than 32. Issue is we are not able to add more that 32 pipelines in it. If more than 32 pipelines selected it gives error - **"Error retrieving data"** and no data is seen.

We have more pipelines now in our ADF and want to add it in the dashboard Metrics. Any pointer to what the issue could be and how to solve this limit?

Answer (score 0):

I test this and I can add 33 pipelines. "Error retrieving data" can be due to the setting of Time range and Time granularity. You can change this to have a try.

[image]

Comment: I have tried that - with time from past 30 mins to 1 week. but still gives same. And now I am getting error after adding more than 30pipeliens. So limit  is not fixed I observe.